# A question about Composition Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, operator-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{B}, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $f:X\to X$ be a transformation such that $f(B)\in\mathcal{B}$ and $f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{B}$ for every $B\in\mathcal{B}$. Also there is $c>0$ such that $\mu(f^{-1}(B))\leq c\mu(B)$.

Define $T_f:L^p(X)\to L^p(X)$, $1\leq p<\infty$ , by
$$T_f(\varphi)= \varphi\circ f, \forall \varphi\in L^p(X)$$

We know that if
$$\sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left\|T^n_f(\varphi)\right\|=\infty, \forall  \varphi\in L^p(X)$$
then for $B\in\mathcal{B}$ with $\mu(B)>0$, we have $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\mu(f^{-n}(B))=\infty$, because if $\varphi= \mathbb{1}_B$, indicator function,  then
$$\left\|T^n_f\varphi\right\|^p_p= \|\varphi\circ f^n\|^p_p= \int|\mathbb{1}_B|^p\circ f^p d\mu=\mu(f^{-n}(B)).$$
Question. What can say if $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left\|T^n_f\right\|= \infty$?